# Not able to test a batch job result using selenium takes 20-25 minutes to complete

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to do the following in my test.

1. Login to the site
2. click on a button to upload an excel file. It will kick off a task
3. Wait for job to complete (takes 20-25 minutes)
4. Verify the output of job (Successful, Failed)

Excel file contains data based on which job will either return success or failure.

I am trying to do this using selenium but the problem is that in the framework we can execute a test for max 10 minutes else it kills the test.

So not sure how to go about automating this scenario.

One of the way i could see is

- First Test --> Just upload the file and kick off the task
- Second Test (depends on First Test) --> verify the results.

Have a you faced similar situation.
Could any of you please suggest the approach for this? or can suggest alternative tool that i could use to automate this scenario.

Comment: How are you waiting the 20 minutes? Can you show the exception you get when the test terminates?

Comment: I have not yet created the test for this.. But discussed with my automation framework teammate who told me about this limitation. so before starting wanted to check if anybody faced similar things in past.

Comment: I never heard of a timeout of 10 minutes. Is it set in your framework explicitly? Maybe you could override it.
In following thread are the default timeouts mentioned:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114976/the-default-value-of-timeouts-on-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I have tests which are waiting more than 10 minutes.